# Select all entries where a given string is a substring of a spesific column in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, sql

I want to query my SQL database for a name. Let's say a certain table contains the column "names" and has two inputs "John Silva" and "Dave Silva". I want to make a query where I get all inputs with the name "Silva" and store them in a way that I can later echo out the result onto my HTML code. Here's what I got so far (keep in mind that it is not working, that's why i came here to ask :) ):

```
    $query = "SELECT ID, email, fullname, permission FROM users WHERE name LIKE '$data'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                    $userName = $row['fullname'];
                    $userHashedPermission = $row['permission'];
                    $ID = $row['ID'];
                    $userEmail = $row['email'];
                }

                if(password_verify('sim', $userHashedPermission)){
                    $userPermission='sim';
                }else{
                    $userPermission='nao';
                }

                $callbackObj->name = $userName;
                $callbackObj->permission = $userPermission;
                $callbackObj->Id = $ID;
                $callbackObj->email = $userEmail;

                $callbackJson = json_encode($callbackObj);
                echo $callbackJson;
                
        }else{
echo "something went wrong"
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a example out the output you like to receive? Also your introduction text does not match your query.. This is missleading.

Comment: Yes I am aware that my query does not do want I want it to do. I would like to get the names "John Silva" and "Dave Silva" in an array if I search for the name "Silva"

Comment: Inside your `while()` loop, once you have the LIKE clause added and suitable % wildcards, you'll need to build an array of users if you are expecting more than one. You'll need to then encode that array. Your current code will only return the last matching row. Can you expand on "not working" please?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you want is `like`.  More importantly:  **learn to use parameters**.

```
$query = "SELECT ID, email, fullname, permission FROM users WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $data)
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($conn, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in your query as

```
$query = "SELECT ID, email, fullname, permission FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%".$data."%'";
```

As per the comments

Do not use `while` loop keep your code as

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){                  
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));                                
    $callbackJson = json_encode($row);              
    echo $callbackJson;             
 }
```

Comment: My code now looks like this `$names = array();

   $query = "SELECT  fullname FROM users WHERE fullname LIKE '%$data%'";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

   if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

      $names[] = $row;
    }

    $callbackJson = json_encode($names);
    echo $callbackJson;

   }else{
    $callbackJson = json_encode($names);
    echo $callbackJson;
   }` But I get an empty json file when i return to the ajax

Comment: This is still not working, the json is empty. Could you please check to see if the parentesis on the query are correct? I would appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have any entries that will satisfy the query because everything else is correct.If `$data` is `Silva` do you have any entry like that in the database.

Comment: Yes, 'Silva' is a name in my data base

Comment: Ok we will ry to get it from both sides just try my edited code.

Comment: I figured it out, my ajax call was messed up... However with your query and logic I can only get the first entry with that name, and I need every entry with that name

Answer (score 0):

I think your sample code and the introduction are totally explaining different thing.

From your introduction, I think you are trying to get all search results with the same surname and then save them in another different way.

If that is your point, we will have better way to sort it out.

Comment: Imagine I have an entry on the 'names' column with the name 'Stack'. I want to get this entry if I search for just 'ack'. And I want to store all the results in a json file so I can send it back to ajax